# zmq fails when doing require('zmq')

Tags: linux, node.js, shared-libraries, zeromq

I have installed zmq using the steps mentioned in [Installation on Linux / bsd without root access](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/wiki/Installation)
Successfully installed but getting error when I start the application. I am working on an environment where I do not have root access.

```
//Index.js
var zmq = require('zmq');
var http = require('http');  
http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); 
res.end(); 
}).listen(3000);
```

Below is the error

```
/home/app/node_modules/zmq/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
ERR         throw e
ERR               ^
ERR Error: libzmq.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERR     at Error (native)
ERR     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
ERR     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
ERR     at require (module.js:384:17)
ERR     at bindings (/home/app/node_modules/zmq/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/zmq/lib/index.js:6:30)
ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
ERR     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
```

Any help on this will be really helpful. Have I missed anything in the installation steps. I goggled and found **"ldconfig"** will resolve the issue. But since in my environment there is no root access, its throwing **command not found or permission denied**

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the zmq shared libraries installed either via your OS distribution's package manager or by manually compiling and installing. On Ubuntu for example, this could be accomplished with `sudo apt-get install libzmq3`.

Comment: Can't use sudo command as the environment does not have root privilege

Comment: Then you'll have to either extract the library from the .deb package in the repository or compile and install manually.